Android 13 - calling onBackPressed() fires onCreate() after navigating back to app
Desired behavior:

From app A launch app B
In app B launch takePhoto contract
After the task is done, return to app A (automatically)
If (manually) returning to app B, do not launch task again

What is happening:

From app A launched app B
In app B launched takePhoto contract
After photo is taken call onBackPressed to get back to app A
When returning to app B (manually), onCreate is called and takePhoto contract is called again

The code:
App A
// This works for android version < 13
// on android 12 and below it works exactly as intended
context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName) ?:
// This works for 13
Intent(action).apply {
    setClassName(packageName, activity)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    putExtras(extras)
}
context.startActivity(launchIntent)

App B:
private val takePhotoContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
    ...
    ...
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (intent.action == TAKE_PHOTO) {
         takePhotoContract.launch(imageUri)
    }
}


Now if I don't call onBackPressed from registerForActivityResult and I navigate back to app A manually and then back to app B, it works fine. onCreate is not called again. How do I either

Stop onCreate from firing after calling onBackPressed
Navigate to previous app without calling onBackPressed

I would also like to keep the app running, so I don't want to kill the app after the task (takePhoto) is done.

you can simply use finish() after the takephoto contract has been called and done capturing image
